# MS Graph API not giving response in SPFX Page, if I add ?env=WebView in Query string

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, spfx

My MS Graph API is not giving the response nowadays if I pass ?env=WebView as a query string in my intranet page which is developed with SPFX. It is working fine without giving me any problem for the last year. For the last 3 to 4 weeks this problem has started.

If I remove the query string and run the page, then it gives me the response from Graph, but along with the query string, it is not giving me the response.

Am using this graph to get my Outlook Calendar Events, Unread Mail count, and Recent Files from Drive.

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does Graph API return any error? Could you share how does the response query looks like?

Comment: Unable to get my mail count AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://777cfeff-82ef-****-*****-b78a830******/microsoft.spfx3rdparty.com was not found in the tenant named --my company name---. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.